# How to integrate recaptcha in liferay 6.2?

Tags: liferay, captcha, recaptcha

I want to create recaptcha in liferay 6.2.I have no idea how to integrate recaptcha in liferay 6.2.

Comment: which reCaptcha do you want to include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with it. If you want to use it when people sign up for accounts, don't look [much further than portal.properties](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#Captcha), just search for recaptcha and adjust the settings in your portal-ext.properties.

If you want to use recaptcha in any custom application, integration is just like in any other application - there's probably nothing really Liferay-specific in there.